# Why event listener on scroll not working on window

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, dom-events

I have a main layout block with the property  `overflow: auto` and because of this, the scroll event is triggered only in this block, although I add a listener to the **window** object.

How do I add a scroll event listener to the window if I don't know the class or id of the specific block on which the event occurs?

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  console.log('scroll!')
});
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: rgb(45, 62, 206);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

Comment: Given that `scroll` events don't propagate up the DOM, what you're trying to do seems a little redundant. Could you please edit the question to give clear details of the issue you're trying to solve as there may be alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm [with Rory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73837275/why-event-listener-on-scroll-not-working-on-window#comment130379274_73837275), this seems like it could be an [X/Y problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). But answering the question asked:

`scroll` events don't bubble, but you can still handle them on ancestor elements by adding a listener for the *capture* phase (`true` as a third argument to `addEventListener`). The capture phase occurs even for events that don't bubble:

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  console.log('scroll!')
}, true); // <===
```

Live Example:

```js
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  console.log('scroll!')
}, true);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

main {
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

main div {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 10px 0;
  background: rgb(45, 62, 206);
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</main>
```

This diagram from the [DOM UI Events specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/uievents/#event-flow) is helpful for understanding capture vs. target vs. bubbling phases:

[image: Graphical representation of an event dispatched in a DOM tree using the DOM event flow, showing the event starting in Window and passing through Document and html, body, and a series of other ancestor elements during the capturing phase, being in the target phase at the target element, and then working its way back from the element to Window in the bubbling phase.]

In events that don't bubble, it's **just** the bubbling phase, not the capture phase, that doesn't happen.

---

*(In the runnable example I made a **small** change to the CSS that's unrelated to the answer; it's just so the Stack Snippet works better. The Stack Snippet console is a div inside the document, so it was being affected by your `div` rule. I just changed the rule's selector to be `main div` instead so it only applied to the elements within `main`.)*